# Best strategy to automate backup ~40 Workstations (WINDOWSXP) at some specific Folder

Tags: windows, backup, windows-xp

We have a LAN at some remote building with around 40 workstations, with no server or backup plan whatsoever.

We're having an auditing next month and we badly need to ensure that some sort of backup is being done on the workstations. The workstations are all Windows XP Pro, a specific folder on every User's Desktop being backup'ed would be enough for us.

The perfect method would be to schedule the workstations, once per day, to Backup some specific folder through FTP to some server with a ftp server. Has anyone ever planned something like this with freeware/opensource based applications ? If so, could you share such plan ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not configure Folder Redirection to redirect the user's My Documents folder to a network share and backup the network share? You can build a file server pretty cheaply and easily and then use a product like [Backup4all](http://www.backup4all.com/kb/ftp-backup-106.html) to back it up to an FTP site.

Comment: If you want to go the other way around for performance reasons, configure the folder on each workstation as shared (with appropriate security) and have a server download and backup the folders on a schedule.

Comment: thank you for your replies. keep in mind that I don't have any server and there's no user management (no €€€), but I'm considering installing CentOS on some crappy machine to host the backups and maybe use SyncBackup, and schedule the backups.